# Stuck with ajax login/logout script in WordPress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

i've got some problems on login/logout script for my ajax-driven page.

First the scenario:
The website should be fully ajax. On ajax request only the content and the menu should be changed. This works fine for normal pages and post, but login / logout give me some trouble on security with wp_create_nonce and check_ajax_referer.

Here's the relevant code:

functions.php

```
/* Login */
function ajax_login_init() {

    wp_register_script('ajax-login-script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/ajax.login.script.js', array('jquery') ); 
    wp_enqueue_script('ajax-login-script');

    wp_localize_script( 'ajax-login-script', 'ajax_login_object', array( 
        'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
        'redirecturl' => home_url(),
        'loadingmessage' => __('Sending user info, please wait...')
    ));

    // Enable the user with no privileges to run ajax_login() in AJAX
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_ajaxlogin', 'ajax_login' );
}

function ajax_login(){

    // First check the nonce, if it fails the function will break
    check_ajax_referer( 'ajax-login-nonce', 'security' );

    // Nonce is checked, get the POST data and sign user on
    $info = array();
    $info['user_login'] = $_POST['username'];
    $info['user_password'] = $_POST['password'];
    $info['remember'] = true;

    $user_signon = wp_signon( $info, false );
    if ( is_wp_error($user_signon) ){
        echo json_encode(array('loggedin'=>false, 'message'=>__('Wrong username or password.')));
    } else {
        echo json_encode(array('loggedin'=>true, 'message'=>__('Login successful, redirecting...')));
    }

    wp_die();
}

/** Logout */
function ajax_logout_init() {   

    wp_register_script('ajax-logout-script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/ajax.logout.script.js', array('jquery') );   
    wp_enqueue_script('ajax-logout-script');

    global $current_user;

    wp_localize_script( 'ajax-logout-script', 'ajax_logout_object', array( 
        'LoggedIn' => is_user_logged_in(),
        'username' => $current_user->display_name,
        'logoutURL' => wp_logout_url(),
        'ajax_url' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php'),
        'logout_nonce' => wp_create_nonce('ajax-logout-nonce')
    ));

    add_action( 'wp_ajax_ajaxlogout', 'ajax_logout' );  
}

function ajax_logout(){

    // First check the nonce, if it fails the function will break
    check_ajax_referer( 'ajax-logout-nonce', 'security' );
    //check_ajax_referer( 'ajax-logout-nonce', 'ajaxsecurity' );
    wp_clear_auth_cookie();
    wp_logout();
    ob_clean(); // probably overkill for this, but good habit
    wp_die();
}

add_action('init', 'ajax_login_init');
add_action('init', 'ajax_logout_init');
```

ajax.login.script.js

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    // Show the login dialog box on click
    $('body').on('click', '.modal-login a', function(e) {
        $('body').prepend('<div class="login_overlay"></div>');
        $('form#login').fadeIn(500);
        $('div.login_overlay, form#login a.close').on('click', function(){
            $('div.login_overlay').remove();
            $('form#login').hide();
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    // Perform AJAX login on form submit
    $('form#login').on('submit', function(e){
        //console.log(ajax_login_object);
        $('form#login p.status').show().text(ajax_login_object.loadingmessage);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            url: ajax_login_object.ajaxurl,
            data: { 
                'action': 'ajaxlogin', //calls wp_ajax_nopriv_ajaxlogin
                'username': $('form#login #username').val(), 
                'password': $('form#login #password').val(), 
                'security': $('form#login #security').val() },
            success: function(data){
                $('form#login p.status').text(data.message);
                if (data.loggedin == true){
                    //document.location.href = ajax_login_object.redirecturl;
                    $('div.login_overlay').remove();
                    $('form#login').hide();
                    $( ".logo a" ).trigger( "click" );
                }
            },
            error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
                alert(err.Message);
            }
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });

});
```

ajax.logout.script.js

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    // Perform AJAX logout on Click
    $('body').on('click','.modal-logout a', function(e) {
        //console.log(ajax_logout_object);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: ajax_logout_object.ajax_url,
            data: {
                'action': 'ajaxlogout',
                'ajaxsecurity': ajax_logout_object.logout_nonce,
            },
            success: function(data){
                console.log(data);
                $( ".logo a" ).trigger( "click" );
            },
            error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
                alert(err.Message);
            }
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });

});
```

The login/logout process works really fine if i do not use the function

```
check_ajax_referer( 'ajax-login-nonce', 'security' );
```

If i enable this code, check_ajax_referer always returns -1, but the ajax query will success. On research it seems that the nonce cannot be verified.

So if i got a refresh of the page i can login without problems, but cannot logout straight afterwards. I need to refresh the page again (which i don't want cause of continious background music). Logout and direct login again has the same problem.

So here are my questions:

1. Do i need check_ajax_referer?
2. Why can i login with activated check_ajax_referer, but not logout direct after login (without nee to refresh page)
3. Same as 2. but other direction

Thanks in advance
Regards, Bandicut

Comment: just to be clear, for "nonce" creation, you should be using function `wp_create_nonce('your-secret-word');`, which you should pass it to 'security' key in data object. 
then you should user `check_ajax_referer( 'your-secret-word', 'security' );` to check if security token is correct. 
Also, in logout script, you use ajaxsecurity key, and should be either using security, or when checking token - `check_ajax_referer('your-secret-word','ajaxsecurity');` since second param is actually key to be used from data object. 
see: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/check_ajax_referer

Comment: please check in private window in browser.

Comment: @niklaz ok... changed it, but problem still remains. It seems that Wordpress changes the security-token on login and logout. Cause i'm only creating the token on full-page-refresh, there might be a problem with wrong checking token.

Answer (score 0):

I feel this code is taken for my blog [Fellow Tuts](http://fellowtuts.com/wordpress/wordpress-ajax-login-and-register-without-a-plugin/) so let me assist you to fix the issue.

As you have not posted the form markup so I'm not sure your nonce `action` and `name` parameters are matching or not. The code to create hidden nonce field in form should be exactly like this:

```
<?php wp_nonce_field('ajax-login-nonce', 'security'); ?>
```

Check the field and update me.